# observeSingleEvent with queryEqual to value doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I want to check if user's device is in my list (for testing). For this I have a small set of values in my Firebase dataset.

It looks like that:
[image: Firebase]

But when I'm trying to check if the user's id is in this list, I'm getting nothing.

```
let childString = "tempfreeuuid/"
let pointref = ref.child(childString)
let query = pointref.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: "FFFFF")

query.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.hasChildren() {
        print("that's good")
    } else {
        print("snapshot has no children")
    }
}
```

And the result is "snapshot has no children".

I've already tried `query.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded)` (doesn't work), `.queryLimited(toFirst: 3)`, and `.queryOrderedByKey()` — these two don't work either.

At the same time this query is working if I'm not trying to use queryEqual.

What am I doing wrong?

**update:** I want to clarify the problem I have. I don't have any results, snapshot is null. At the same time if I'm using `queryLimited(toFirst: 1)` instead of `queryEqual`, I'm getting one result from the table to work with. It seems to me it's not about snapshot issues, it's about query without any results.

Comment: you should have to check snapshot as a "Dictionary" value.

Comment: How do I check the snapshot if it doesn't really exist (it has no children)? I am not able to check it because it's null. I checked its value, and it is Optional(<null>).

Comment: you can check if dictionary is nil or not

Comment: I think you are using the wrong `OrderedBy`. Can you try using `queryOrderedByValue` and `queryOrderedByChild` instead of `queryOrderedByKey`

Comment: Wow, it works! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't approve your comment as a right answer because it's not an answer. If you post it as an answer below, I'll be glad to do that.

Comment: @AndréKool I was about to post an answer when I noticed you already helped lithium. Can you post your comment as an answer, so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong `OrderedBy` method. Because you are using `queryOrderedByKey` the `queryEqual` function will check if its equal to the Key while you want to compare it to the Value.

Instead you should be using `queryOrderedByChild` or `queryOrderedByValue` to make sure you compare the right values.

[Here is the reference to the firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data) explaining how queries (specificly `queryEqualToValue` in your case) work.